# awk Removing space from output

Tags: objective-c, macos, unix, awk

I am using `@"df -lH | grep \"/Volumes/*\" | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8\"\"; print $0 }'"` for getting locally-mounted volumes path. but if volume name contain two or more space (Leopard  1). its(awk) removing space from output.

Output:

```
$df -lH

Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s3    81G    61G    19G    77%    /
/dev/disk0s2    81G    72G   8.2G    90%    /Volumes/Leopard  1  2     3
/dev/disk0s4   158G    47G   111G    30%    /Volumes/Backup  

$ df -lH | grep "/Volumes/*"
/dev/disk0s2    81G    72G   8.2G    90%    /Volumes/Leopard  1  2     3
/dev/disk0s4   158G    47G   111G    30%    /Volumes/Backup  

$ df -lH | grep "/Volumes/*" | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""; print $0}'
     /Volumes/Leopard 1 2 3
     /Volumes/Backup
```

can anyone please help me out?

Comment: This question would be easier if you could please post your output of `df -lh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `awk`'s output field separator is a single space. So the output of your `awk` command is completely expected. To get the result you want, you'll need to use some sort of regex, so try this instead with `GNU awk`:

```
df -lH | awk '/Volumes/ { sub(/^(\S+\s+){5}/, ""); print }'
```

Or if you have `GNU sed`:

```
df -lH | sed -nr '/Volumes/s/^(\S+\s+){5}//p'
```

Results:

```
/Volumes/Leopard  1  2     3
/Volumes/Backup
```

*EDIT:*

I see that `BSD/OSX awk` [doesn't support interval expressions](http://awk.freeshell.org/AwkFeatureComparison) unfortunately. Therefore the safest way would be to do this with `awk`:

```
df -lH | awk '/Volumes/ { sub(/^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +/, ""); print }'
```

or with `sed`:

```
df -lH | sed -n '/Volumes/s/^[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+//p'
```

This should also be highly portable! HTH.

*EDIT:*

For Mac OSX 10.8 with 8 columns, simply extend the regex:

```
df -lH | awk '/Volumes/ { sub(/^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +/, ""); print }'
```

or with `sed`:

```
df -lH | sed -n '/Volumes/s/^[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+[^ ]\+ \+//p'
```

Comment: first command is giving me     /dev/disk0s2    81G    72G   8.2G    90%    /Volumes/Leopard    3   4        4
    /dev/disk0s4   158G    47G   111G    30%    /Volumes/Backup output

Comment: @ParagBafna: No problem; I've added a `sed` solution too. Good-luck!

Comment: your solution will work fine for 10.5 to 10.7 Mac osx but in 10.8 df output contain 8 columns.

Comment: @ParagBafna: Added an update for you, hopefully it will work for you. Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

This is easier using the `mount` command, which has simpler output than `df`, and `perl`, which supports non-greedy matching:

```
:; mount | perl -pe 's/.*? on //;s/ \([^\)]*\)$//'
/
/dev
/Volumes/pro Time Machine 2
/Volumes/b
/Volumes/p
/net
/home
```

Notice that I do have a volume mounted with spaces in the mount point.

Answer (score 1):

```
df -lH | grep "/Volumes/*" | perl -pe 's/[^\%]*\%//g'
```

if you want to do it in awk:

```
df -lH | grep "/Volumes/*"|awk '{gsub(/[^\%]*\%/,"");print}'
```

Comment: You never need grep with awk. `df -lH | awk '/\/Volumes\//{gsub(/[^%]*%/,"");print}'`. I also dropped the "*" which wasn't doing anything for your RE and got rid of the backslashes before the %s as those aren't RE metacharacters so they don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of this command, might help you parse and get the info

```
mount | column -t
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `column -t` will not help much, since the big problem is how to handle mount points that contain spaces.